# Reading big .txt file in iPhone/iPad device and AES256Cryptor

Tags: iphone, ios, aes

I am developing iPhone/iPad application witch contains data in .txt file that is encrypted with AES256Cryptor. File with data is very big(~10MB). 
When application starts:

1. reads .txt file
2. decrypts string from file(for decryption uses key hardcoded in
   NSString)
3. string is parsed and put into NSDictionary (~ 40000 records)

Application doesn't use network(must be offline).
My questions are:

1. Data(in .txt) is relatively valuable and I would not like to see it
   hacked. How safe do you think this is? Do you have any seguestions?
2. Reading from file and saving to NSDictionary takes a lot of time(~5s
   for reading .txt, ~5s for parsing an saving to NSDictionary):

.

```
NSString *encryptedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *encryptedData = [GTMBase64 decodeString:encryptedString];
NSData *decryptedData = [[RNCryptor AES256Cryptor] decryptData:encryptedData password:@"password" error:&error];
NSString *dataString  = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decryptedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSArray *records = [dataString componentsSeparatedByString:@"separator"];

for( "record in records") {
  save record to dictionary...
}
```

How can I improve it?

Comment: You need to get a better handle of what actions take the longest. If you could just save encrypted data, you'd avoid the first step with GTMBase64. If you can use the NULL character in your string as a separator, you could more easily create the individual records. Newer iOS devices have dual cores, so you could devise a way to parse the records in two chunks - find the separator close to half way through your string, then have two threads working on each half, then join them together when done. Do this all in the background and keep the user amused so the time does not seem so long.

Comment: thx David. I will amuse users with UIProgressView:).